# Conditionally expose Spring web service operation

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-ws

We're using Spring web services in our application and have a requirement to make a new operation, intended for internal testing, available only in our dev and test environments. I know how to handle such a requirement in Axis (we have one such module, where we simply add or remove the operation from the "allowedMethods" parameter in our wsdd) but I have no idea how to accomplish this in Spring, and haven't had much luck searching online. What are our options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring profiles will help you:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html

```
@Configuration
@Profile("dev")
public class ProductionConfiguration {

    // ...

}
```

You can use profiles on a Bean:

```
@Component
@Profile("dev")
public class DevDatasourceConfig
```

Or in the XML:

```
<beans profile="dev">
    <bean id="devDatasourceConfig"
      class="org.baeldung.profiles.DevDatasourceConfig" />
</beans>
```

You could also specify what profiles are in use by WebApplicationInitializer:

```
@Configuration
public class MyWebApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        servletContext.setInitParameter("spring.profiles.active", "dev");
    }
}
```

or

```
@Autowired
private ConfigurableEnvironment env;
...
env.setActiveProfiles("dev");
```

or web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
    <param-value>dev</param-value>
</context-param>
```

or JVM parameter:

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=dev
```

or environment variable:

```
export spring_profiles_active=dev
```

Comment: This looks like what we need - time for some reading. Thanks!